# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

Tags: magento-1.9, database, payment

we integrated custom payment method. once it redirect to payment page after clicking on place order, its displaying below error. but same module worked fine in another site.

```
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'sitename.payucheckout_api_debug' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE
 `payucheckout_api_debug`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in your database if **payucheckout_api_debug** table is present or not which is not their as per the error which you posted above.

if it is not their, then check **core_resource** if your script record is their or not. if it is their then check for a version of your script and the recorded one, from which you can decide your script was executed or not.

If you don't get any record for your script then check for errors in your sql script.

if you find the record but version are not matching then either delete that record from this table so that your script will re execute and create a table or update the version of your script accordingly.

for more details of upgrade or installer script you can refer

1) http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

2) https://www.sitepoint.com/magento-install-upgrade-data-scripts-explained/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `payucheckout_api_debug` is not presetn in db. how to check in `core_resource `  that our script is recorded or not ?

Comment: open `app\code\<codePool>\<nameSpace>\<module>etc\config.xml` their you find a node between `<resources>` and `<setup>` node search for this code that table for example `<resources> <contact_setup>  <setup>`  `contact_setup` s the code.

Comment: you can come for a chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40477/room-for-ashish-madankar-and-user9999

Comment: when i checked `core_resource` table, i found : http://prntscr.com/ba2trc

Answer (score 1):

In my case, disabling and enabling the module again did the trick.

To disable, go to `System->Advanced->Advanced->Disable Modules Output` page. Here, find the module `Payu_PayuCheckout`. Select `Disabled` from drop-down in-front of module, and `Save config`. Once the page refreshes, repeat the steps but select `Enabled` from the drop down this time.